# Cannot find the dual function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

[image: Picture]

The picture shows an example of solving the integer problem with a decomposition method. However, what I am trying to ask is about the dual function part instead of the integer part. As you can see, the integer variables are relaxed. However, I cannot find the same dual function as the author shows.

The dual function should be as:

$$d(\lambda)=-b^T\lambda+min_{x\in X}\sum_{i\in I}(c_i^T+\lambda^TH_i)x_i \label{1},$$

where $b$ is the shared resouce ($11.1$ in the problem), $I$ is the set of agents. In this case, it should be:

$$d(\lambda)=-11.1\lambda+min_{x\in X}\sum_{i=1}^4(c_i^T+\lambda^TH_i)x_i.$$

Let us focus on the minimization part, which is:

$$\min_{x\in X}\sum_{i=1}^4(c_i^T+\lambda^TH_i)x_i.$$

Then for the first agent $i=1$, denote by $x_{11}, x_{21}$ its two variables, we have,

$$\min_{x_1\in X_1}(c_1^T+\lambda^TH_1)x_1=(x_{11}+x_{21}+\lambda^T(x_{11}+x_{21}))=(\lambda^T+1)x_{11}+(\lambda^T+1)x_{21}.$$

Similarly, we have for $i=2$

$$\min_{x_2\in X_2}(c_2^T+\lambda^TH_2)x_2=(-2x_{12}+x_{22}+\lambda^T(5x_{12}+x_{22}))=(5\lambda^T-2)x_{12}+(\lambda^T+1)x_{22},$$

for $i=3$

$$\min_{x_3\in X_3}(c_3^T+\lambda^TH_3)x_3=(0.5x_{13}-x_{23}+\lambda^T(x_{13}+x_{23}))=(\lambda^T+0.5)x_{13}+(\lambda^T-1)x_{23},$$

for $i=4$

$$\min_{x_4\in X_4}(c_4^T+\lambda^TH_4)x_4=(-3x_{14}+0.5x_{24}+\lambda^T(x_{14}+x_{24}))=(\lambda^T-3)x_{14}+(\lambda^T+0.5)x_{24}.$$

Now, we can write the piecewise function about $\lambda$. **But here, I cannot get the same function as the author.**

For example, if $\lambda \in [0,2/5]$, I think these variables should take the larger values, i.e. $x_{12}=2.1,x_{23}=1.1,x_{14}=1.2$, because the coefficients are negative, while the others take zero value, because the coefficients are positive. Hence, the dual function in $[0, 2/5]$ is

$d(\lambda)=-11.1\lambda+2.1(5\lambda-2)+1.1(\lambda-1)+1.2(\lambda-3)=(-11.1+10.5+1.1+1.2)\lambda-4.2-1.1-3.6=1.7\lambda-8.9$, which is totally different from the author.

**I know there must be something wrong. My understanding of the dual function might be incorrect. Can someone please help me with this?**

Comment: You should be careful about reasoning like "set the variables with positive coefficients to $0$ and the variables with negative coefficients to their maximum value", because sometimes, setting a positive-coefficient variable to a positive value lets us set a negative-coefficient variable to a larger value as well; this can happen in regions $X_1$ and $X_3$. I don't think it's the reason for the discrepancy, but it's something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

The intent in the given solution appears to be that we *don't* drop the integrality constraint on $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$. With this modification, though your overall approach is correct, the optimal choice of primal variables for $\lambda \in [0,2/5]$ is $$x_1 = (0,0), \quad x_2 = (2,0), \quad x_3 = (0,1), \quad x_4 = (1,0).$$ This changes $2.1(5\lambda-2)$ to $2(5\lambda-2)$, $1.1(\lambda-1)$ to $1(\lambda-1)$, and $1.2(\lambda-3)$ to $1(\lambda-3)$, and altogether we get $$-11.1\lambda + 2(5\lambda-2) + (\lambda-1) + (\lambda-3) = -8 + 0.9\lambda,$$ just as in the given solution.

---

There is another discrepancy that I believe is simply a calculation error. For higher values of $\lambda$, we will drop the $2(5\lambda-2)$ term, then the $(\lambda-1)$ term, then the $(\lambda-3)$ term as each one becomes positive, because we can always switch the corresponding $x_i$ to $(0,0)$. This gives us: $$d(\lambda) = \begin{cases}-8 + 0.9\lambda & 0 \le \lambda < 2/5 \\ -4 - 9.1\lambda & 2/5 \le \lambda < 1 \\ -3 - 10.1\lambda & 1 \le \lambda < 3 \\ -11.1\lambda & 3 \le \lambda\end{cases}$$ (It is very easy to subtract $10$ from $0.9$ and accidentally get $-8.9$ rather than the correct $-9.1$.)